# Ignore input in shell script

Tags: shell

I am exporting a .txt file in shell script which has some entires. THis shell script is called by python code. When I run the python code it asks the input as:

```
Enter the list : aaf|hgj|hju
```

after giving there input (aaf|hgj|hju) and press enter its shows me the output as :

```
aaf belongs to : city name
hgj belongs to : city name
hju belongs to : city name

(aaf|hgj|hju) are these entries are present in .txt file.
```

My requirenment is if I provide the input as (aaf|hgj|hju|ggg) where ggg is not present in .txt file it should show me :

```
ggg is wrong input
aaf belongs to : city name
hgj belongs to : city name
hju belongs to : city name
```

means for other three it should me as it is.

below is the sample code for shell script :

```
#!/bin/ksh

export fName="/fsnadmin/SAAS_SUPPORT/pod_data_from_FM.txt"

pdcats=""
        pdcas=""
        export fstrs=$1
        #dcs="US1 - ADC"
        pList=`awk '{ print $1 }' RS="|" <<< $fstrs`
        for item in ${pList[*]}
        do
                item=`echo $item|sed 's/\^//'|sed 's/\\$//'`
                len=${#item}

                if [ $len -gt 3 ]; then
                        item=`echo $item|sed 's/-MC//'|sed 's/\^//'|sed 's/\\$//'`
                fi
                item=`echo $item`

                pdcats=`cat $fName| egrep -e "$dcs" |awk -F':' '{print $1}'|grep -i ^$item\$`

                if [ "$pdcats" != "" ]; then
                        len=${#pdcats}
                        if [ $len -gt 3 ]; then
                                pdcas=`echo $pdcas"^"$pdcats"-MC$|"`
                        else
                                pdcas=`echo $pdcas"^"$pdcats"$|"`
                        fi
                fi
        done
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck getting it working. Did you have a question?

Comment: Thanks Marc for improving the format.
Yes I have q question that how Can I show my input (aaf|hgj|hju|ggg) for 'ggg' is wrong if its not present in .txt
Please go through my third text line for details where my question is mentioned.

Comment: @Himanshu, you need to edit your question to add the actual question. Don't bury it in a comment. Show your actual output. Don't ask us to debug your code for you. You need a concrete question about a specific part of your code.

Comment: Okay Glenn I'll ask my question in separate thread and will keep in mind your advice.